# Saturation for line drawn in Tkinter canvas

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I would like to draw lines with `Tkinter` in python. I think for that purpose I can use `create_line()` on a canvas. The different line segments should appear consecutive in time (so that an animation is created). I think I can achieve this by just using `create_line()` on two points, than pausing for a few millisecond, drawing the next line etc. In the end I would like to imitate hand writing, that's why I would like to have small pauses between displaying the lines.

Now my problem is that I would like to change the saturation of the color of the line.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your only color-related options are to specify an rgb value for canvas object. To change the saturation you will need to do a little math on the rgb values.